# Clarification of elementary matrices in commutator group of infinite general linear group.

Tags: group-theory, k-theory, linear-groups

I have the following small insecurity:

Considering the infinite general linear group $GL(R)$ of some commutative ring $R$ with 1 [Whitehead (p. 4 Theorem 1)](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/jhcw2.pdf) and [wiki/k-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory#K1) tells us that the commutator group is $E(R)=[GL(R),GL(R)]$ generated by elementary matrices.

Now [wikipedia/elementary_matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) tells me
also matrices with an element $r \neq 1$ on the diagonal is an elementary matrix (called row-multiplication matrices).

> Can someone please verify that in our commutator group we just
>   consider $E(R)=<\{M \ | \ M=I+rE_{i,j}, i\neq j, r \in R\}>$ i.e. the
>   group generated by elementary matrices except of these
>   row-scalar-multiplication matrices/ generated by elementary matrices
>   with diagonal-entries 1 or do we also need those as generators?

Following my senses and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092804/abelianization-of-general-linear-group) it should be only elementary matrices with diagonal-entries 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagonal matrices with finite support and determinant 1 are generated by elementary matrices. This can be seen as follows: for $i\neq j$, define $e_{ij}(r)=I+rE_{ij}$, and for $r$ invertible, define $q_{ij}(r)=e_{ji}(r)e_{ij}(-r^{-1})e_{ji}(r)$. Then $q(r)=q_{12}(r)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -r^{-1}\\ r & 0\end{pmatrix}$. So $q(r)q(-1)$ is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}r^{-1} & 0\\ 0 & r\end{pmatrix}$. Thus $q_{ij}(r)q_{ij}(-1)$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is 1 except $r^{-1}$ at $ii$ and $r$ at $jj$. From this it is immediate to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much. From this it is indeed immediate to conclude.