# Surjective group homomorphism from $GL(n, \mathbb{F}_{p})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $m$. Does there exist a surjective group homomorphism from $GL(n, \mathbb{F}_{p}) \rightarrow G$ for some $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and prime $p$?

Comment: What is $m$? You introduced $m$ and then did not refer to it again.

Comment: I guess the question is: What finite groups are homomorphic images of $GL(n, \mathbb{F}_{p})$ ? This reduces to: What are the normal subgroups of $GL(n, \mathbb{F}_{p})$? This seems easier to handle.

Comment: See for instance https://online.tugraz.at/tug_online/LV_TX.wbDisplaySemplanDoc?pStpSplDsNr=13888

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092804/abelianization-of-general-linear-group), the abelianization of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is (almost always) the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and in particular it is always cyclic; so if $G$ is abelian but not cyclic, any morphism $GL(n, \mathbb{F}_{p}) \rightarrow G$ must factor through a cyclic group, and thus it cannot be surjective.

Comment: if suppose $G$ is non-abelian group, then can you say something?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It depends on $G$. For most finite groups $G$ the answer is no.

Comment: @SunnyRathore: It follows immediately that if $G$ is a quotient of a finite general linear group, it must have cyclic abelianization.